# What is the difference and typical use between the id, database id and persistent id properties of tracks in iTunes and Apple Music

Tags: applescript, itunes, apple-music

On MacoS the properties of a filetrack object retrieved from iTunes or the newer Apple Music app show it has three similar properties

- id
- database id
- persistent id

What is the difference and typical use between the *id*, *database id* and *persistent id* properties of tracks in iTunes and Apple Music, it is not clear to me.

Comment: This page helped me with my project https://documentation.help/iTunesCOM/interfaceIITObject.html

Comment: Can you show where you're getting ID from?

Comment: Using applescript